# Attempting to prove a conserved quantity for incompressible Navier-Stokes PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, symmetry, fluid-dynamics

I am looking for feedback on this attempt to prove a conserved quantity for incompressible Navier-Stokes

$$(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} = \nu \Delta \mathbf{u} - \nabla p$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}=0$$

where $\mathbf{u}=(u,v,w)$
No dimensional constants are given. They are not required to state initial conditions. There are no boundary conditions given. Initial conditions are $\mathbf{u}(x,y,z,0)=\mathbf{u}_0(x,y,z)$

The PDE has scaling invariance; it is preserved by the transformation

$$(x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime)=k(x,y,z)$$
$$(u^\prime,v^\prime,w^\prime)=\frac{1}{k}(u,v,w)$$
$$t^\prime=k^2t$$
$$p^\prime=\frac{1}{k^2}p$$

This is the finite transformation of the scaling group; it is a Lie group; its infinitesimal operator need not be listed here.

This means the solutions $\mathbf{u}(x,y,z,t)$ and $p(x,y,z,t)$ are homogeneous functions. Scaling is taken to mean "multiply the argument by the number $k$" and as a result "the function is multiplied by $k$ raised to a certain power".
Then, the velocity is homogeneous in $x,y,z$ of degree 1 and homogeneous in $t$ of degree -1; the pressure is homogeneous in $x,y,z$ of degree 2 and homogeneous in $t$ of degree -2 ("pressure" is $p/\rho$, where $\rho=\mbox{const}$ is the fluid density)

To ensure the proper scaling properties of $\mathbf{u}$ and $p$, we have

$$x \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial y}+z \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial z}=\mathbf{u}$$
$$t \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} = -\mathbf{u}$$
$$x \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+y \frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+z \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}=2p$$
$$t \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -2p$$

This gives (use a sym algebra package)

$$\boxed{\mathbf{u}=\frac{x}{t+C}\mathbf{F}\left( \frac{y}{x}, \frac{z}{x} \right)}$$
$$\boxed{p=\frac{x^2}{(t+C)^2}F\left( \frac{y}{x}, \frac{z}{x} \right)}$$

Here the "$t+C$" comes from time-translational invariance of the PDE; $C=$const. $\mathbf{F}$ and $F$ are arbitrary functions.

Transform the solution under scaling:

$$\mathbf{u}^\prime=\frac{x^\prime}{t^\prime+C^\prime}\mathbf{F}\left( \frac{y^\prime}{x^\prime}, \frac{z^\prime}{x^\prime} \right)=\frac{kx}{k^2(t+C)}\mathbf{F}\left( \frac{ky}{kx}, \frac{kz}{kx} \right)=\frac{1}{k}\mathbf{u}$$

$$p^\prime=\frac{x^{\prime 2}}{(t^\prime+C^\prime)^2}F \left( \frac{y^\prime}{x^\prime}, \frac{z^\prime}{x^\prime} \right)=\frac{k^2x^2}{k^4(t+C)^2} F \left( \frac{ky}{kx}, \frac{kz}{kx} \right)=\frac{1}{k^2}p,$$

it transforms correctly as expected.

Because we see the separation of variables, quantities such as

$$\frac{u}{v-w}$$
$$\frac{w^2}{p}$$

etc. are conserved (and scale-invariant), because the time dependence cancels out.

Could you kindly provide feedback whether this claim is true. It would be very helpful if specific mistakes (if any) in the proof are pointed out.

Answers should be about the 3-dimensional equation and its solutions; and all variables should be clearly stated as well as their relationship with the Cartesian coordinates $x,y,z$ and the time $t$.

Also, all conditions stated in the problem must be followed, particularly about the initial, boundary conditions and any dimensional constants.

Comment: Scaling invariance does not imply homogenous solutions! There are lot more kind of solutions of this equation that are not of this form!

Comment: Both $\mathbf{u}$ and $p$ must be relative invariants of the scaling transformation, $\mathbf{u}^\prime=A\mathbf{u}$ and $p^\prime=Bp$, where $A,B=$const. If they are not homogeneous, how do they transform under scaling transformation? If you have examples and details, could you post an answer.

Comment: No, it just says that if $u$ is a solution, then $u'=Au$ is also a solution, it doesn't say that $u'=u$ ...

Comment: I never claimed $\mathbf{u}^\prime=\mathbf{u}$. What is claimed is: if $\mathbf{u}$ is a solution, so is $\mathbf{u}^\prime$, where $\mathbf{u}^\prime=\frac{1}{k}\mathbf{u}$, as required by the the finite transformation of the scaling group. Both $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{u}^\prime$ are solutions indeed; and they are Different from each other, as shown in the boxed equations! One of them is the scaled down "version" of the other. I am surprised that this is not clear.

Comment: I was talking about the $u'$ in your comment. then since $u'$ is another solution, there are no constraints on $u$. So it is not homogeneous ...

Comment: What did you mean by your statement "$u$ is invariant of the scaling transformation $u'=Au$" if it is not $u'= u$?

Comment: $\mathbf{u}$ is a RELATIVE invariant. There is a published theorem about relative invariants of the scaling transformation and that they ARE homogeneous functions. This has been known since the times of Lie

Comment: Give the definition then ...

Comment: I can give that... Could you remove your downvote on this question. We are learning in this thread, and an upvote would be fair.

Comment: I know about PDEs and N-S but I don't know any Lie theory so I don't know what you mean by relative invariants. To me, what you have written is that you can, starting from one global in time solution of N-S, create a family of solutions to N-S, related by the above described scaling. This is true, and I suspect whatever you did with the CAS follows, (I don't know what to make of it). However, I would definitely not say that $u$ is itself a homogeneous function. For instance this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold-Beltrami-Childress_flow is clearly not a homogeneous function.

Comment: If you want $u$ itself to be a homogeneous function, that would entail ensuring that $u_k = u$ in some fashion, where $u_k$ is some transformed verison of $u$. This is what LL is talking about.  Leray thought of using backwards-in-time self-similar solutions to construct finite time blowup but it didn't work out.  Forwards self-similar solutions (and discretely self-similar ones) are still being researched today, one source for some of the known results is Tsai Tai Peng's "Lectures on Navier-Stokes Equations", I don't know much more; google gives e.g. https://math.unice.fr/~fab/publis/sim.pdf

Comment: This posted question is built on Lie. Regarding the ABC flow: it is homogeneous, but the **shorthand** in writing it is misleading, because it involves dimensional constants e.g. $x_0=1 m,y_0=1 m,z_0=1 m$ which are omitted. Its full form s/be $\dot{x}=A\sin z/z_0 + C \cos y/y_0$, where $A,C$ are constants with resp. dimensions. It is clearly homogeneous. This is all clear to physicists, because expressions such as "$\sin z$" are forbidden in physics due to them having improper units. It always is "$\sin z/z_0$" or such, which makes the argument dimensionless. Always check for constants!

Comment: On invariant theory, here is a link to an article and many good references:
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Invariants,_theory_of

Comment: I do not see why one can say that $\sin(z/z_0)$ (ignoring the other terms) is homogenous. Maybe you mean to say that it is homogeneous if we extend it to a function $(z,z_0) \mapsto \sin(z/z_0)$. But that is distinct from the function that I was referring to, $z\mapsto \sin(z/z_0)$. Adding the $z_0$ as an input seems to be essentially equivalent to the first idea I was talking about, namely constructing a family of solutions ($\sin(z/z_0)$) starting from one of them ($\sin z$); then I feel like any invariants are just properties of the original solution $z\mapsto \sin z$?

Comment: I actually cannot think of a function that is not homogeneous, if you always allow me to turn any variables $z$ into homogeneous versions $z/z_0$?

Comment: $z$ has units of meters; $\sin z = z - \frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-...$ doesn't have defined units; it is not homogeneous in $z$. In physics, we always have $\sin (z/z_0) = (z/z_0) - \frac{z^3}{z^3_0 3!}+\frac{z^5}{z^5_0 5!}-...$. It is now dimensionless, and homogeneous of degee 0 in $z,z_0$.

Comment: I still see no reason to bring into the discussion units, dimensional analysis or for that matter physics. I understood the question as it is currently phrased as one of pure mathematics, and in particular about the nondimensionalised Navier--Stokes equations. In such a setting I would maintain that (A) $\sin z$ can't be called homogeneous, by which I mean it is not a function $f$ such that for some $s\in\mathbb R$, for every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $\lambda^s f(\lambda z) = f(z)$  , nor is it absolutely homogeneous like a norm;

Comment: (B) analogously to the comments of this previous question of yours https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687111/is-the-general-solution-to-the-heat-equation-u-t-gamma-u-xx-a-homogeneous-f , I don't think you gain anything from this theory, as if you generate a family of solutions related by this invariance, any invariants would just be properties of the original solution. The solutions that are given by homogeneous functions(in the sense I defined) in some form are those called "self-similar" in the literature, as in my earlier comment/link

Comment: The NSE in my question contains $\nu$, the kinematic viscosity with $[\nu]=m^2/s$ and not the Reynolds number as would be in the case of the nondimensionalized N-S eq. Nodimensionalization imposes ad-hoc parameters e.g. $L,U$ as added initial conditions; and also, sets the scale. On the opposite, the big question with the NSE is the possibility of scaling-induced blow-up. This is an entirely mathematical problem; but intuition from physics also helps, see e.g. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/03/18/why-global-regularity-for-navier-stokes-is-hard/

Comment: You don't need to tell me about intuition from physics, *I study PDEs*. I was trying to focus your question and distill out something that maths can answer, not make it fuzzier with more intuition. It is common to set $\nu = \frac1{\text{Re}}$.  Everything you are saying about units (if you think it is at all relevant, and I don't), and your definition of the word "homogeneous" which is non-standard in the context of PDEs, should have been in your question. I won't ask why you think blow up will be scaling-induced. Thank you for telling me about the theory of invariants.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, what I wrote I did not to get into an argument, but because this is how I see it. I am seeking other viewpoints, hence my question! I am really trying to understand your points. I have read your comments many times, but they are lacking in detail. Could you please post an extended answer, backing your points more rigorously. I may not agree with what you will say, but will surely appreciate the details you will provide! It will help me to understand your view against the dimensioned NSE; your view against homogeneous solutions; and your view against similarity at different scales.